# Kibana: Limit results to last 5 minutes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a realtime visitor counter on my Kibana Dashboard. To achieve that I created a unique count on the IP addresses and limiting the results to the last 5 minutes with the query:

```
@timestamp:now-5m
```

This was working since a few month ago. I don't know whether something has changed in Kibana, at least the @timestamp field is still present, but it seems like the "now-5m" syntax is not working anymore. The result set is always empty.

Can someone provide me with the correct query or an alternative solution on how to create a realtime visitor counter with Kibana Visualizations?

Here is the underlying query:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [],
    "filter": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-5m",
                  "lte": "now-5m",
                  "time_zone": "Europe/Berlin"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
            "gte": "2020-08-27T22:00:00.000Z",
            "lte": "2020-08-28T21:59:59.999Z"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": [],
    "must_not": []
  }
},
```

[image: Kibana Discover]

I think the issue is here:

```
"gte": "now-5m",
"lte": "now-5m",
```

Which should be probably:

```
"gte": "now-5m",
"lte": "now",
```

But how do I achieve this in the query field?

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't work anymore? Any error you can share? How does the underlying query look like (get it from Inspect)?

Comment: @Val thanks for the hint, the inspect was giving some more information. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you have two different constraints on the same field? The second one is from the time picker and the first is a custom one? How did you specify it? Through a filter?

Comment: Kibana is creating these constraints. First one is my filter to get results from last 5 minutes for the visitor counter, second one is from Kibana Dashboard to show results of the current day for all visualizations.

Comment: I'm using the "Discover" query in Kibana. See Screenshot in my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to switch to the Lucene expression language, and then you simply need to write this:

```
@timestamp:[now-5m TO now]
```

That defines a `range` query

Another (better) solution is to create a filter (Add filter) with the "is between" operator, instead of writing a query into the search bar. It will work better and you can stick with KQL in the search bar.

Comment: I am getting the error for the KQL query:
[esaggs] > Expected "(", value, whitespace but ">" found. timestamp:>=now-5m and timestamp:<=now -----------^

Comment: Hmmm, yes, right, can you try to switch to the Lucene query language instead of KQL ?

Comment: That worked out, thanks a lot! So the solution is to switch to Lucene query language and use the "[now-5m TO now]" expression. Strange that the previous syntax suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Another (better) solution is to create a filter (Add filter) with the "is between" operator, instead of writing a query into the search bar. It will work better and you can stick with KQL in the search bar.